# Pass extra values with start_url without meta to Scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have scraped items from a spider and I am writing another spider which uses a search engine to fill in some missing data. I would like to have items from the first spider updated, row by row.

However, I don't see how I can pass the current row or start_url from __init__ method.

I know that I can pass request.url in meta to child requests, and then parse meta to extract company name, but it looks awkward.

```
class DuckDuckGoComSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'duckduckgo.com'

    def __init__(self, csv_file_path, *args, **kwargs):
        self.csv_file_path = csv_file_path
        super(DuckDuckGoComSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        with open(csv_file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
            for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
                self.start_urls.append(
                    f'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q="website" {row["name"]} {row["location"]}')

    def parse(self, response):
        results = list(response.css('.result__url::attr(href)'))
        if len(results) > 0:
            for i in range(6):
                yield response.follow(results[i], callback=self.parse_item)
        else:
            self.logger.debug('No more products')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        il = DDGItemLoader(response=response)
        il.add_value('url', response.url)
        il.add_css('title', 'meta[property="og:title"]::attr(content)')
        il.add_css('description',
                   'meta[property="og:description"]::attr(content)')

        item = il.load_item()
        yield item
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) function. This will allow you to create the request yourself and choose to send the additional data in the meta data (what I would do) or to create one dictionary and to lookup your data in your `parse_item` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to pass values to parse methods, as mentioned by casper:

1. Compose requests in `start_requests()` and pass required data in `meta`
2. Create any data structure on a class level you can use to reference needed data. The data can be updated in a spider or in a custom pipeline

Using `meta` looks like this:

```
class DuckDuckGoComBatchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'duckduckgo_batch.com'

    def __init__(self, csv_file_path, *args, **kwargs):
        self.csv_file_path = csv_file_path
        super(DuckDuckGoComBatchSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        pages = []
        with open(self.csv_file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            self.fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
            for row in reader:
                url = f'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q="website" {row["name"]} {row["location"]}'
                meta = {}
                for f in reader.fieldnames:
                    meta[f] = row[f]
                page = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)
                pages.append(page)

        return pages

    def parse(self, response):
        results = list(response.css('.result__url::attr(href)'))
        if len(results) > 0:
            yield response.follow(results[0], callback=self.parse_item,
                                  meta=response.meta)
        else:
            self.logger.debug('No more products')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        il = DDGItemLoader(response=response)
        il.add_value('website', response.url)
        il.add_css('website_title', 'meta[property="og:title"]::attr(content)')
        il.add_css('website_description',
                   'meta[property="og:description"]::attr(content)')
        il.add_value('name', response.meta["name"])

        item = il.load_item()
        for key in response.meta:
            if key in self.fieldnames:
                item[key] = response.meta[key]
        yield item
```